# Добавить пробелы в адресах

Tags: python

Подскажите пожалуйста регулярное выражение для установки пробелов в слитных адресах.

Что есть:

```
pr.Lunacharskogo11k1_lit
Stachek47A
Industrialnyj26k24
```

Что нужно получить:

```
pr.Lunacharskogo 11 k1_lit
Stachek 47A
Industrialnyj 26 k24
```

Нужно как то выдергивать текст, число, текст и число и потом конкатенировать через пробел.

Comment: По Вашей логике `Stachek47A` должен преобразоваться в `Stachek 47 A`

Comment: так тоже пойдет

Comment: ([^\d]+)  это выхватывает текст до первой цифры   ([^\A-Za-z|.]+)  выдергивает цифру

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Программно можно так:

```
str1 = 'pr.Lunacharskogo11k1_lit'
index_word = []
index_digit = []
result_str = ''
for index, character in enumerate(str1):
    if character.isdigit():
        index_digit.append(index)
        try:
            result_str += ' ' + str1[index_word[0]: index_word[-1] + 1]
            index_word = []
        except:
            pass
    else:
        index_word.append(index)
        try:
            result_str += ' ' + str1[index_digit[0]:index_digit[-1] + 1]
            index_digit = []
        except:
            pass
result_str = result_str[1:]
print(result_str)
```

Выдаст:

```
pr.Lunacharskog 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Регулярное выражение для разделения. Взято отсюда: [ссылка](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50214293/4827341)

```
\d(?=[^_\d\W])|[^_\d\W](?=\d)
```

Comment: a
8
k        чтото не то выдает ((